# Is Neo4j graph database sufficient to itself for all query types?

Tags: database, sql, nosql, social-networks, query

Neo4j eases relationship traversals => especially useful for a social network for instance.

But are there any scenarios when it's advised to associate an additional relational database (or other NoSQL database that isn't specifically oriented graph) for specific query types.

In short, can Neo4j be sufficient to itself for all query tasks?

Comment: Given that the only operations in SQL are essentially join and filters, and that filters are trivial in Neo4j, while joins can be simulated by following a relation with a given name, I would say yes. I am not sure that it would be a very efficient way to query, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to think of it this way.  SQL relational databases are tuned to run SQL queries as fast as possible, whether or not that is the best way to represent your data.

Each of the NoSQL products have generally arisen because SQL databases are not a good match for representing a particular type of data, and are tuned for that use.  If you are using a well respected product for the problem its designed to solve, then you are probably in good shape.

Go outside this, and it tends to bite you.